# How updatepanel before validation in asp.net. use telerik

Tags: asp.net

Who can help me?

I have problem. when change radcombobox of telerik, so validation of textbox handle. But I want validation only handle when click `button1`.

follown code:

asp.net

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
            <AjaxSettings>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting  AjaxControlID="RadComboBox1">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadComboBox1" />
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Label1" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="cg_id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"></telerik:RadComboBox>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TravelConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Categorys_Group]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </asp:Panel>
        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TextBoxRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                    ControlToValidate="RadTextBox1" ErrorMessage="Không được để trống!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

code behind:

```
protected void RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = RadComboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        }
```

Now, I want when change RadComboBox1 validation , `TextBoxRequiredFieldValidator` don't handler. It only handler  when click button.

How do i do?
Thanks help me!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox CausesValidation="false" ID="RadComboBox1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="cg_id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"></telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I know how do it.

I add  `ValidationGroup="SelectionFormValidationGroup"` for controls validation.